# Numpy reapeat array attached to array?! what is the syntax here?

Tags: python, numpy, repeat

So, I currently need to understand the following code properly:

```
J = p['M'].repeat(p['N'],1).T
```

p is a dictionary in which the entry under key M is simply an array, the T transposes, that much is clear.
But, the only version I can find for the repeat function is syntax in the form of

```
numpy.repeat(array , repeats [,axis])
```

This leaves me wondering what the meaning of a syntax of type array.repeat(something) actually means and I can neither find an answer in my head or the internet for now. This is numpy though, isnt it? It is imported, without being tagged with an 'as' clause.
So currently am on a machine without a python/numpy shell installed to simply try it, so I thought I give this a shot: What is repeated how many times?
My first interpretation would be p['M'] is repeated p['N'] times along the first axis, then transposed, but every example specifying an axis I find uses something like axis=1.
Thanks a lot =)

Comment: `a.repeat(repeats, axis)` is equivalent to `numpy.repeat(a, repeats, axis)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is another version of repeat in numpy: numpy.ndarray.repeat

Please see the documentation [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.repeat.html)

Hope this helps

Comment: although there is not much there, i feel more confident in my interpretation. still confusing me, but hey, if it comes down to it, i ll have to wait a few hours and just try :)